# How can I avoid Permission Errors in Python scripts executed via docker-compose?

Tags: python, docker-compose

I've been attempting to run [RL software](https://github.com/davidADSP/SIMPLE) using docker-compose. I have had success creating some basic docker containers as well as using docker-compose, but I am not very experienced with it.

Following the installation process in the README file of the repo I have successfully built a docker image. The next step is a Python script that install additional elements to the container.

```
docker-compose exec app pip3 install -e ./environments/sushigo
```

On `bash ./scripts/install_env.sh sushigo` I get the message `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable`. The scripts keeps on running but a few lines later I get the following issue:

```
Installing collected packages: sushigo
  Running setup.py develop for sushigo
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/app/environments/sushigo/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/app/environments/sushigo/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps --user --prefix=
         cwd: /app/environments/sushigo/
    Complete output (4 lines):
    running develop
    running egg_info
    creating sushigo.egg-info
    error: could not create 'sushigo.egg-info': Permission denied
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/app/environments/sushigo/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/app/environments/sushigo/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps --user --prefix= Check the logs for full command output.
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8899:8899
      - 6006:6006
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app/
    tty: true
    container_name: selfplay
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
```

My best guess is that Python lacks the authorizations to write additional files inside the container. How can I avoid this error ?

For additional information:

- I'm running everything as a root user
- I'm using Ubuntu through WSL2

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving that information here because the fixes suggested did not seem to solve the issue, and it might be useful to some.

My issue was that pip & docker were installed and run as a root users. This is a source of a lot of permissions errors on a variety of software.

A clean install of my WSL2 kernel with properly configured user permissions was the only good solution on my end.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command:

```
docker-compose exec app chmod -R 777 ./environments
```

in order to give the appropriate permissions to available environments.
And then the command:

```
docker-compose exec app pip3 install -e ./environments/sushigo
```